# How to prevent zeros from being input before non-zero digits?

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, truncation

In C#, WinForms how would you stop the following inputs:

0000000000001234556

0000.123456

00000123456.123456

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want 1234556 instead of 000000001234556

Then you can convert it in `Int`,`Double` or any other Datatype as  you want

2nd option is use the `keypress` event

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == ascii of 0)
        {
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `KeyPress` event and define a state that, if input is == '0' then ignore, else, wait for a non-zero input. Then change the state to accept 0s.

Since you do not show code, I will not either

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event handler to the `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` events. Inside the event handler check if the `KeyEventArgs` `KeyCode` is 0 and if the length of your `TextBox.Text` property is 0. If so set the `KeyEventArgs` `Handled` property to false.